# Can a Safari browser extension remove itself?

Tags: safari, safari-extension

The api for Google Chrome Extensions happens to offer [a `chrome.management.uninstallSelf()` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-uninstallSelf). This allows an extension to get rid of itself when it's no longer needed.

(Firefox and Edge offer partial compatibility with the Chrome extension mechanism, but neither support this method. Unfortunately.)

Does the Apple Safari browser extension mechanism, or any part of the Safari setup, offer any way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no API available to extensions to permit this in Safari.

In fact, not even the Safari Extension Gallery offers this capability (and it's the only website that can offer buttons to install extensions with one click).

Safari Extension uninstallation is controlled by the user through **Safari** > **Preferences** > **Extensions**.